# How to prevent re-render of entire list on addition of new element in React

Tags: reactjs

I would like to render only newly added elements instead of re-rendering the entire list when a new element gets added to the list. I tried adding key prop but still all elements are rendering.
This is an example code for my use-case https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-poincare-qcsvn?file=/src/App.js, here we can see console log for all list elements when we add a new element to the list.

Comment: Why do you care if the render functions of each item is called again? Do you make heavy calculations in any of the render functions? Does it have any measurable impact? The reconciler inspects the key prop and will not make any DOM changes for items with stable keys.

Comment: Yeah, there is some heavy rendering for each list element, like some huge images

Comment: That is because you defined your component inside the App, check out my answer for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because you defined your CommentView component inside the App Component
any update on the state cause the component to be re-render and react treats these CommentView recreated version as it is a completely different component lets assume react think you change the div to span it has no idea they are the same old component

**Hoist the component outside the App component**

```
const CommentView = React.memo(/**/)
const App = () => {/* rest without the CommentView definition */}
```

you can also use Pure component instead of memo if you want, which compare shallowly

```
class CommentView extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    const comment = this.props.comment;
    return (
      <h1 key={`comment-${comment.id}`}>
        {console.log("Rendering", comment.id)}
        {comment.id}: {comment.msg}
      </h1>
    );
  }
}

export default function App() {
// rest of code
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your id is not unique. If you add this, it will be unique:

```
 {
    id: comments[comments.length - 1].id + 1,
    msg: "C"
 }
```

Changing the state means that React triggers an update when we call the `setState` function (in React hooks, you would use `useState`). This doesn't only mean the component's render function will be called, but also that all its subsequent child components will re-render, regardless of whether their props have changed or not.

`React.memo` only does the shallow comparison.

So you need to supply your own comparison logic as a second parameter.

```
function MyComponent(props) {
  /* render using props */
}

function areEqual(prevProps, nextProps) {
  /*
  return true if passing nextProps to render would return
  the same result as passing prevProps to render,
  otherwise return false
  */
}

export default React.memo(MyComponent, areEqual);
```

Comment: No, it seems it doesn't happen because of the same key. at least it must work correctly in the first add which has the unique key 'c'

Comment: Tried adding comparison function in the sandbox, but that function is not even getting called

Comment: That's exactly because it is recreated instead of re-render, check out my answer for more detail, let me know if any thing remains unclear